# No warnings if category is used but isn't added into target(Any way check it automatically?)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compilation, warnings, objective-c-category

I have a category "NSObject+completeOnce". And I use it for main app, watch, widget. But I haven't added it into watch and widget target. Of course I must do it.

My Question is:"Why I don't see any warnings or linking errors in this case? Can I force them?" I have more than 100 classes in my project and sometimes do such mitakes :( It would be good to find some way to check it before runnig.

Category declaration:

```
//Category is added only into main target.
@interface NSObject (completeOnce)
+ (void)completeBlockOnce:(void(^)(void))block forKey:(NSString*)key
@end
```

Usage:

```
@implementation SomeOtherClass
+ (void)method
{
    //It crashes for for widgets.
    //And Here is no any warnings. Also no linking errors at all
    [NSObject completeBlockOnce:^{
       //Some Code
    } forKey:@"FixMigrationBug_1_0_to_1_6"];
}
@end
```

I am sure that I have only one declaration of this method. And I have to emphasize that it is the same problem for all categories. Even for categoryes of my custom classes with 99% unique method name.

[image]

Comment: What methods are defined on this category? Are you sure they don't conflict with other existing names? What do the call sites of these methods look like?

Comment: Thanks for attention, I've added some info. Guess it contains answers to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So the core of the problem is that you import the headers on all platforms, but when you don't include the actual compiled `.m` for those targets, they crash, correct? If that's the case, then my guess is that you don't get a compiler error because the compiler has all it needs in the header files: a declaration of a method. The compiler doesn't care if the method is there or not, it just needs to see what it looks like. (Up to the linker to verify.) The linker might not be able to statically determine this stuff, since it's in a category -- it's up to the runtime to see.

Comment: Just a hunch, at least. I'll look into this further to see if there is a deeper explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is a compound issue. You're right in looking for two types of errors -- compiler warnings/errors, and linker errors. You're not getting either, for two reasons:

1. There is actually no reason for the compiler to give you a warning. All the compiler needs in order for you to make a method call is the *declaration* of the method (for it to line up the arguments correctly, prevent common user error, etc.). It doesn't actually need to know that the method will be linked in somehow; that's the linker's job. In this case, since you do declare the methods in a header and include the header, the compiler is satisfied and you will not get a warning, since as far as the compiler is concerned, the method will exist later.
2. The linker doesn't give an error for the missing methods because [Objective-C does not produce linker symbols for methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1490/_index.html) (see the Objective-C header on that page). Objective-C is inherently a very dynamic language, so it can be impossible to know what a particular method call will do until runtime; in fact, it is possible to define methods at runtime which do not exist statically. The linker only requires class information, which it has; evaluation of methods is left up to the runtime.

These two things combined lead to the behavior you're seeing. The only way to be sure that these methods don't exist is to simply try to call them at runtime -- where now, you're getting an exception (if uncaught, leads to a crash), since they have not actually been included in the app binary.

Comment: I think you are right. But I am looking for some way to avoid such crashes in the future. It might be that there are no solution. But I think that I must at least try. Because I work with "widgets" and "Apple watch". There are 1000+files in the project. And I am unable to check it myself =(. Such mistakes appear once in a month again and again, like that man with a spoon=( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9VDvgL58h_Y

Comment: Probably my question title doesn't correspond to my needs =( I'll try to be more accurate in this.

Comment: @ZevsVU There is no compiler-supported solution because there can't be one, for the reasons above — there is simply no way statically to know whether the methods will be there or not. You can, though, solve this with tooling: you can write a script that automatically goes through all of the files in your project and makes sure they are added to all targets. Or if you have a list of files which should be on some targets and not others, adds them to the appropriate ones.